# Show accuracy for each class in every given test data using sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, text-classification

I have something to ask.

I've trained my sklearn Logistic Regression classifier with 10 thousand training data in Python. 
I have 2 thousand test data and I use accuracy score to show the accuracy and confusion matrix.. but both only show overall accuracy of all test data.

what I want is for example:

Test data 1: "abc"

Accuracy of class A given test data: 80%

Accuracy of class B given test data: 10%

Accuracy of class C given test data: 10%

Test data 2: "def"

Accuracy of class A given test data: 50%

Accuracy of class B given test data: 30%

Accuracy of class C given test data: 20%

and so on for the rest of all the test data.
and I want to show it in table like this.
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTVpP.png)

is it possible to that using sklearn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the example provided by you, I think what you are asking is probabilistic prediction for each of your test data points. You can do it easily by using the `predict_proba`  method of the LogisticRegression class (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.predict_proba). This will give you the probabilities of each of the classes. The returned matrix should have a size of `2000 x 3` in your case. You can multiply them by 100 to get the necessary percentages for each of your class.

Hope that helps.

Comment: yes! it works like charm now. :) thanks for the help @Abhinav